# How to copy row by row data from one gridview to other which is on other form by double click on row C# WinForm

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

How i can transfer record(Row By Row) of 1st grid-view to 2nd grid-view which is on separate form By double click the row of 1st .... C# WinForm

Image 1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/O62RD.png

Image 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcLqZ.png

Image 3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LEqg.png

Comment: have you tried anything so far? can you share some code?

Comment: You can pass a filtered DataView or a BindingSource. You can add a constructor to the second form that accepts a DataTable/DataView/BindingSource or use a public property or a public method to pass the data object after you have created the Form instance.  Or use a *Manager* class object that handles the transaction (it can also contain the logic to filter the data). Best if all Forms classes that can share the data implement the same public Interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data of the selected row through the event "CellDoubleClick".

And then use `Application.OpenForms Property` to get the instance of `Form2`.

To access the dgv2 that in Form2, you can define a property to achieve it.

Form2.cs:

```
// Define a property to access dgv2
public DataGridView DGV
{
    get { return dataGridView2; }
    set { dataGridView2 = value; }
}
```

The following is a simple demo you can refer to.

Form1.cs:

```
Form2 form2;

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the instance of Form2
    form2 = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];

    // Save the selected row's items into a list
    List<string> items = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; i++)
    {
        items.Add(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[i].Value.ToString());
    }

    // Add new data to dgv2
    DataGridViewRow dr = new DataGridViewRow();
    dr.CreateCells(form2.DGV);
    dr.Cells[0].Value = items[0];
    dr.Cells[1].Value = items[1];
    // call the property "DGV" in Form2.cs
    form2.DGV.Rows.Add(dr);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add some test data into dgv1
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
    { ColumnName = "species", DataType = typeof(string) });
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn()
    { ColumnName = "weight", DataType = typeof(string) });
    dt.Rows.Add("Cat", "12");
    dt.Rows.Add("Mouse", "3");
    dt.Rows.Add( "Pig", "308");
    dt.Rows.Add( "Elephant", "1652");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

// Open form2
private void btOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using delegate and events, you need to pass entire selected row object on row double click